# How can I sort an array of EKEvent by date?

Tags: objective-c, eventkit

I have an array that stores events fetched via a predicate; I want to sort them by date. I read that I have to "call sortedArrayUsingSelector: on the array, providing the selector for the compareStartDateWithEvent: method', but I don't know how to use it exactly. Could someone provide me an example?

Here's my array: `NSArray *events = [store eventsMatchingPredicate:predicate]`
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you have your array, consider:

```
NSArray *sortedArray = [events sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(EKEvent *event1, EKEvent *event2) {
    return [event1.startDate compare:event2.startDate];
}];
```

This would sort the events by start date, using the built-in NSDate [- compare](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDate_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSDate/compare:) function.

The `- sortedArrayUsingComparator` method takes an `NSComparator` block, which is defined as:

```
typedef NSComparisonResult (^NSComparator)(id obj1, id obj2);
```

You can basically think of it as a block (a lambda-function) that takes two arguments, and you return an `NSComparisonResult` member that explains what the ordering of the two given objects are.  The type of the object depends on what you shoved into your array, in this case `EKEvent`s.  How you sort them is up to you; read up on [NSComparator](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_DataTypes/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/NSComparator) for more info and the rules.  `NSArray` will call your block multiple times, presenting two items each time, until the array is sorted.

Now, lucky you, `EKEvent` exposes a selector which knows how to compare to `EKEvents`.  `NSArray` has another method, [sortedArrayUsingSelector:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSArray/sortedArrayUsingSelector:) that you can use, and just tell it to use the comparison selector that EKEvent exposes:

```
NSArray *sortedArray = [events sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(compareStartDateWithEvent:)];
```

Now `NSArray` will call `- compareStartDateWithEvent:` each time it wants to compare two items.  If that is the ordering you want, you can use it.  Otherwise, use the comparator method above.

Comment: Wow, thanks man! Appreciate the explanations! I'm mostly learning all this by myself and from other people's code so sorry if these questions seem obvious to you!

Comment: We all start somewhere.  The selector stuff can be a bit confusing at times.  Check out the [Objective-C Runtime Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ObjCRuntimeRef/index.html) for a peak at what's going on under the covers.